# Saving/Restoring a fragment's state when adding/removing it with fragment manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have an activity that has several fragments, which are added and removed dynamically. I noticed that each time a fragment is added with `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(containerViewId, fragment, tag).commit()`, the Bundle received in the fragment's method `onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` is `null` and when calling `fragmentManager.beginTrasaction().remove(fragment).commit()`, the frament's method `onSaveInstanceState(Bunlde) is not called.

So is there a way to make the fragment save/restore its state when adding/removing it with fragment manager?

If the fragment is retained, then the `Bundle` in `onCreateView` is always `null`.